# datepicker calendar using bootstrap and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I hope someone can help me with this issue.
I am trying to use the datepicker from the following link
The problem is that I want to be able to use a few features but don't know how.
1)I want to be able to unset a specific date from my angular controller
2)I want to be able to clear all the selected dates from the datepicker calendar.

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html

Here's how my code looks:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Pickup Dates</h5>

        <!--Inline DatePicker-->
        <div class="datepicker" ng-click="dateSelection()" ng-selected="selectedDates!=-1">
        </div>
    </div>

        <script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        multidate: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'

    });
</script>
```

My angular controller is as follow 
    $scope.dt = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDates');

Then I have a function that gets triggered when a button is clicked.
Once the button is pressed, all dates are saved and then the selected dates
should clear from the calendar but instead a new calendar gets created.

```
    $scope.createSearches=function() {
        /*saving dates code*/

    $('.datepicker').datepicker('clearDate')

    }
```

I read the documentation and not sure how to use the clearDate event so if someone can help me with this and also how to unset specific dates from the controller, I will really appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: Note that 'clearDate' is not a method, but rather an event.  It is "fired when the date is cleared, normally when the 'clear' button (enabled with the clearBtn option) is pressed."  Have you tried using the 'setDates' method and pass an empty array?  e.g. `$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDates', []);`

Comment: Thank you David. Your answer makes sense and I tried it but it creates another datepicker calendar for somereason.
I trigger this code when pressing a button
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDates', []);
and on the screen,another calendar is added.
Do you know how I can workaoround this?

Comment: Have you thought of using a datepicker directive like this one http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers ?. It's a better practice in angularJs, and you should avoid refering to DOM elements from you controller

Comment: @cpu2007: Can you setup an example?